# Apollo=Express GraphQL error, cannot find module graphql

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, typeorm, typegraphql

I am trying to set up a graphql express server with apollo, express, typeorm, and graphql, however I am getting this error now that I have implemented the UserResolver.ts file. I have already tried installing graphql and even have downgraded it to 14.2.1 but it still doesn't work. Here is the source code:

index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import express from 'express';
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server-express';
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { UserResolver } from "./UserResolver";





(async () => {
    const app = express();
    app.get('/', (_req, res) => res.send('hello'))

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [UserResolver]
        })
    });
    // my line idk if it works 
    await apolloServer.start();

    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
    
    app.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log("express server started");
    });
})()

// createConnection().then(async connection => {

//     console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
//     const user = new User();
//     user.firstName = "Timber";
//     user.lastName = "Saw";
//     user.age = 25;
//     await connection.manager.save(user);
//     console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id);

//     console.log("Loading users from the database...");
//     const users = await connection.manager.find(User);
//     console.log("Loaded users: ", users);

//     console.log("Here you can setup and run express/koa/any other framework.");

// }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

UserResolver.ts

```
import { Query, Resolver } from 'type-graphql';

@Resolver()
export class UserResolver{
    @Query(() => String)
    hello(){
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "7434006a",
   "database": "graphqldatabase",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.5.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.2.1",
    "pg": "^8.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "typeorm": "0.2.41"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/config/postgres.config.ts"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I just deleted all of my node-modules folder and ran npm install